# Scrolling a vertical stack of collection views

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

On my view controller, I have a bunch of collection views that each scroll horizontally. I am able to scroll my collection views fine, but I am not able to get to the bottom-most collection view, because the screen doesn't scroll vertically. What do I need to do to make the whole screen scroll vertically? I tried adding a scroll view behind these collection views but that doesn't seem to do anything.

[image]

Do I need to put the collectionviews into a tableview? A lot of apps (like Netflix) have this functionality...

Comment: If they are fixed number (i.e. always 3 collection views), you just could put them in a scrollview, to put them in a scrollview, Apple has some guideline for this, make a scrollview, then make a "content view" which is an ordinary UIView, pin it in all directions in the  scrollview, then put the 3 collection views inside the content views with a chain of constraints (i.e. each one pinned to the other, and the uppermost is pinned to the upper of scrollview, and the lowermost is pinned to the bottom of scrollview)

Comment: Read this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH24-SW1

Comment: Ok will go through that, thanks. And if it's not fixed? Meaning, different users will see a different number of collection views...

Answer (score 0):

Your main view that contains the subviews (collection views) is not scrollable by default. You will need to add a UIScrollview and then add the uicollectionviews to the scrollview.

A good tutorial on how to make scrollviews work with autolayout can be found here: https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/